# Checkbox group error

Tags: java, user-interface

The method add(JCheckBox) is undefined for the type CheckboxGroup

Any ideas fellows?

```
private CheckboxGroup group2;

group2 = new CheckboxGroup();
group2.add(firstbox);
group2.add(secBox);
group2.add(thirdbox);
```

edit,asked to add more code.

```
firstbox = new JCheckBox("checkbox"); // Setting Label
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.add(new JLabel("|"));
panel.add(firstbox);     
panel.add(RadButton1);
panel.add(RadButton2);
panel.add(RadButton3);

group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(RadButton1);
group.add(RadButton2);
group.add(RadButton3);


add(panel);
```

Comment: The example on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxGroup.html) page appears to say you should just put `add(firstbox);`, not `group2.add(firstbox);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using awt. When you construct the CheckBox instances, you should use a constructor that takes a CheckBoxGroup as a parameter:

- [Checkbox(String label, boolean state, CheckboxGroup group)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html#Checkbox%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.awt.CheckboxGroup%29)
- [Checkbox(String label, CheckboxGroup group, boolean state)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html#Checkbox%28java.lang.String,%20java.awt.CheckboxGroup,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

Thats because CheckboxGroup is used for CheckBox (package java.awt) not JCheckBox (package java.swing)

For swing buttons you should use ButtonGroup

```
private ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
group2.add(firstbox);
group2.add(secBox);
group2.add(thirdbox);
```

Comment: Ok done,getting java.lang.NullPointerException error
Adding them to panel like so panel.add(firstbox);

Comment: Where and how did you declare checkboxes and Radbuttons? at what line does the exception occure?